# CCRepeatForever not resuming immediately after sleep

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, sleep, repeat, resume

In a cocos2D powered iphone app, I use the CCRepeatForever action to make the background pass by. It works fine when I debug the app (build and run via XCode). Even if I quit the app and resume it, no problem.
However when I bundle the app into an .ipa for beta testing I get a weird problem :
At launch the background passes by nicely. 
But if I quit the app and resume the game later, the app takes me back where I left it, with everything working but the moving background. And after a time (roughly proportional to the time since I quitted the app) the background starts moving again as it should, without me doing anything particular.
Is this a know issue ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OH, I had a very similar problem a little while ago.  I would pause the game, then on resume nothing would happen, then it would suddenly jump and I'd be swarmed with monsters.

I can't tell you precisely where to look, but here's what I was doing:

I had a timer that was not using the (ccTime)dt to calculate time, but was using an NSDate timestamp.  The problem was that I had an event to be scheduled at a certain time based on the date, but was using the dt to figure out when to trigger the event.

As far as I could tell, pausing the game was halting the scheduled events, so the "dt" wasn't incrementing at all, but the system clock kept ticking, so what ended up happening is that I would pause for say 10 seconds, the system clock ticked up and triggered, but the "dt" was adding into a float timeElapsed, and until that caught up, nothing happened.

What you probably need to look for is something inside a scheduled event that is using an NSDate or a unix timestamp or the iPad/iPod system clock.  When you halt the simulator, the system clock doesn't seem to run the same way it does on an actual iPad.

Sorry, I don't know EXACTLY how this stuff works, but I also went through an agonizing time with a similar problem and it was based on the system timer.  Just make sure you're pausing everything with the CCDirector properly and make sure you're not using any system clock stuff for game timing